# Passing multiple queries from a Web Part in order to filter a view

Tags: filter, query-string

I am aware that using URLs like `http://site/Lists/MyList/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Title&FilterValue1=ExactTitle&FilterField2=Year&FilterValue2=ExactYear` will display a filtered view showing T`itle=ExactTitle` and `Year=ExactYear`.

I would like to create a page on site which will function as a search form and pass the Title and Year parameters to the URL in accordance with user input. Specifically:

- How do I create a button (aptly titled "Filter Title & Year") which will pass *both* parameters entered into the Title-searchbox and the Year-searchbox?
- Can I create a drop-down list for the year field and add it - rather than an editbox - to the page? If so, how?

Solutions not requiring access to SharePoint Designer are preferred, and an explanation for dummies will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

**tl;dr** Wondering how I can build a custom search page which creates a filtered-in-advance view URL, in accordance with user input.

Answer (score 0):

Your try with the connection properties of web part to filter the listview
[For how to use conncetion you can refer link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-Filter-Web-Part-to-a-List-View-Web-Part-1aabfd67-2e2e-4912-9230-6cb43a2c140a)

Answer (score 0):

Insert a Script Editor Web part and insert HTML code for the UI + JavaScript code for the logic. Something like this (not tested):

```
<input type="text" id="titleSearchInput"/>

<select id="yearSearchInput">
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="goSearch()">Search</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function goSearch(){

       // 1. Get the HTML elements
       var titleSearchInput = document.getElementById("titleSearchInput");
       var yearSearchInput = document.getElementById("yearSearchInput");

       // 2. Get the values from these inputs
       var titleSearch = titleSearchInput.value;
       var yearSearch = yearSearchInput.options[yearSearchInput.selectedIndex].value;

       // 3. TODO: check if titleSearch/yearSearch are null
       //          + escape values

       // 4. Build the search URL
       var URL = "http://site/Lists/MyList/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Title&FilterValue1=" + titleSearch + "&FilterField2=Year&FilterValue2=" + yearSearch;

       // 5. Redirect to the URL
       window.location.href = URL;

       return false; // TO avoid a postback because of the click on the button
    }
</script>
```